# How do you handle unsolicited responses (like incoming calls/texts) when handling SMS with a GSM modem?

Tags: sms, response, gsm, modem

I've tried to develop a GSM modem library for handling SMS built around `system.io.ports.serialport`.

It does'nt handle unsolicited responses very well, in particular incoming calls.

I have resorted to sending AT hangup commands for each incoming call, however the unsolicited responses still popup even while you are performing other tasks.

This makes it quite difficult to handle correctly.

Comment: Do you want a sollution for your problem or a library to replace your code? Maybe you should change the title or the question to reflect it better.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a separate thread that acts as a session handler, with a message queue interface towards the rest of your app. It should wait on inputs from either your application (to initiate a session) or your modem (incoming calls). When it's rebuffing an incoming call, session initiation requests from your application can wait.